# Why invariant geodesics of translation can't have at least two intersections?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I can't understand the red line well. Seemly, if $\tilde \gamma_1\cap \tilde \gamma_2$ has at least two points, it will contradict with the simple connectivity. I want to know why it is ?

**PS(2024-3-26)**: As the hint of  Moishe Kohan, the right way is to use the Hadamard Theorem.

**Hadamard Theorem**: Let $M$ be a complete Riemannian manifold, simply connected, with sectional curvature $K\le 0$. Then $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, $n=\dim M$; more precisely $\exp_p:T_pM\rightarrow M$ is a diffeomorphism.

If there are at least two points, assuming two of them are $p,q$, then, there are two different vectors $u,v\in T_pM$ such that $\exp_pu=\exp_pv =q$. It  contradict with $\exp_p$ is diffeomorphism.

> Picture below is from the  260th page  of [do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry](https://library.lol/main/0A30B69FEAD8267DB0705B4F81764346).
> [image]

Comment: Hint: What does the curvature condition tell you about intersections between geodesics? (I think you are also missing the assumption that $\tilde M$ is complete and simply connected.)

Comment: Read section 3, chapter 7 of do Carmo's book.

Comment: @MoisheKohan  Haha, thanks, I just thought Haradama theorem. The simple connected really be  misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the intersection contains just one point, $P$. Where must that point go *after* the translation, i.e., what is $f(P)$? It must lie on both geodesics, because we're assuming both are (setwise) invariant under $f$. But the only point on both geodesics is $P$. So we get $f(P) = P$, i.e., $P$ is a fixed-point of $f$. But $f$ has no fixed points (by the opening clause of that sentence), so that's a contradiction.

Comment: I know why one point is impossible. But I don't know why two point or more is impossible. Maybe,  I didn't make my question clear.

Comment: If you have two points, $P$ and $Q$, presumably the idea is that a path from $P$ to $Q$ along $\gamma_1$ and then back to $P$ along $\gamma_2$ is, for some reason, a non-contractible path, so that it becomes a nonzero element in $\pi_1$. That's probably proven in an earlier lemma.

Comment: See also Moishe's comment ... which presumably relates to an earlier lemma as well.